# How do I see which commit I was in before running a git pull?

Tags: git

Can I get **the hash of the commit I was in before updating a project**? 
Is that possible?

Disclaimer: I tried, but I could not find a duplicate to this question.

Comment: See what `git reflog` tells you.

Comment: Wow, perfect. Thanks for that.

Comment: I disagree, a duplicate shouldn't need answers on its own, then it's not really a good duplicate.